# How to write unit testing script using unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to write a unit test cases using unittest where my input is set of images and output is set of images with boundary box in the text, also it generate co-ordinate of the boundary boxes. How can I write test script for that using unittest pyunit framework.

So I have written unittest script to test api is working or not, response should be json / and list format and response of image file format should be png,jpg format, which is working now. I have below test case scenario need to test but how I will check? I don't know.

If optional keys are not passed to API, it should not throw an error. (opposite for compulsory ones) 8) The implemented route should throw/return error if GET request is passed instead of POST. 9) If valid path but invalid file name is provided, you should see respective error. 10) In case of invalid path, you should see respective error message. 11) There is specified set of keys which are compulsory to be passed to APIs, if not it returns an error 12) verify for session time out.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import sshtunnel
import unittest
class TestSequentialExecutions(unittest.TestCase):
   
def setUp(self) -> None:
        a=10
    def test_API(self):
        self.resp_list = []
        # API url
        url = ['dummy url','dummyurl']

        # Additional headers.
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        # Body
        payload = [{'input': 'dummy path'},
                  {"path": "dummy"}]

        # Test case-1 checking valid API  is routed or not
        # convert dict to json by json.dumps() for body data.
        for i in range(len(url)):
            resp = requests.post(url[i], headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload[i], indent=4))
            self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
            self.resp_list.append(resp.json())
            #Test case-2 to check input file is in JPG ,PNG format or not
    def test_fileformat(self):

        n = len(self.resp_list[1])
        my_list = [1]*n
        empty_list=[]
        extensions = ['png','v']
        for filename in self.resp_list[0]:
            if filename.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg')):
              empty_list.append(1)
            else:
              empty_list.append(0)
        self.assertEqual(my,empy_list) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Actually I am trying to write test script for below github code: https://github.com/eragonruan/text-detection-ctpn

Comment: Please give me some idea .. so that i can write my test case for above secnario.

Comment: I have formatted your code and added your comments into the main body of the question. Feel free to continue editing (and please familiarise yourself with the code formatting tools here - they are essential to making a question readable).